# Android.sdk cannot find tools\android.bat: setup unreliable

Tags: android

It's not the first time I install Android SDK on several machines. It did work and sometimes it doesn't. So for this time today the tools directory doesn't contain android.bat.

I'm very surprised that setup procedure can be so unrealiable after so many versions releases. When I click on uninstall it doesn't even propose to reinstall and just delete everything.

So If I reinstall will I get exactly the same result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best is not to use the recommanded exe version but just the zip version.